# ActsAsTaggableOn Undefined Method '[]=' for nil:NilClass - Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, acts-as-taggable-on

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Below, at the bottom of my post, I updated it with the fix for this issue, partly thanks to Narasimha Reddy. Hope it helps anyone with a similar issue after upgrading to Rails 5.2. UPDATE: ActsAsTaggableOn 6.0 is out and fixes this issue.**

I have recently upgraded to Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5, and switched my development database to PostgreSQL (9.3.18, gem: 1.0.0). Previously, this issue wasn't occurring, and only the aforementioned changes have been made since then. I use ActsAsTaggableOn (5.0.0) gem for a review form that uses two lists: love_list and improve_list. Now, when submitting the form, I receive the following error:

```
    NoMethodError in CityReviewsController#create
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line 56)

 56:   @new_city_review = @city.city_reviews.build(city_review_params)
    @new_city_review.user_id = current_user.id  

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/mvp1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:206:in `process_dirty_object'
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:184:in `set_tag_list_on'
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:45:in `love_list='
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `public_send'
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute'
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:44:in `block in _assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in `each'
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in `_assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `_assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:314:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:154:in `build_association'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:270:in `build_record'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:106:in `build'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:319:in `build'
app/controllers/city_reviews_controller.rb:56:in `create'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
better_errors (2.4.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Request
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+KJueLU14yKJPxcTyhPbg0cQFkShT0oYjl9ddJR2pGKSDroJTReEMw7zukg3mpB5Gf3O8HhGYHDbYYqtNoM6Pw==",
 "city_review"=>
  {"title"=>"Blah Blah Blah",
   "score"=>"3",
   "love_list"=>"Schools / Education, Night Life, ",
   "improve_list"=>"Schools / Education, Taxes, ",
   "description"=>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium.\r\n" +
    "Proin varius tincidunt purus, congue hendrerit ex interdum sed. Sed interdum, nibh ac lacinia vulputate, neque tellus ultricies nibh, eget vehicula ligula diam sit amet diam. Donec aliquam blandit laoreet. Cras at efficitur est. Phasellus quis enim vitae nisl sodales feugiat non sit amet tellus. Phasellus commodo, risus vitae luctus porta, nulla leo luctus massa, vel tempus odio tellus at nulla. Ut dictum nibh urna, quis scelerisque odio pellentesque ut. Sed at pretium nisi. Maecenas facilisis enim sed molestie gravida."},
 "commit"=>"Submit Review",
 "city_id"=>"lakewood"}
```

In my server terminal I receive a 500 error:

> "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)"

In Rails Console, I receive the same error. My Controller is posted below:

```
class CityReviewsController < ApplicationController
# Main controller for City Reviews
  before_action :set_city_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
  # Below - Sets City for method actions of City Review.
  before_action :set_city, except: [:edit, :update, :destroy] 
  # Below - Multiples the score value that is initially 1 out of 5 and factors it by 20.
  before_action :multiply_score, only: [:create, :update]
  # Below - Sets user related params and IDs 
  before_action :set_user_params, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    # Below - adds punch counter to City Review.
    @city_review.punch(request)
    @city_review_comments = @city_review.comments
  end

  # GET /city_reviews/new
  def new
    @new_city_review = CityReview.new
  end

  # GET /city_reviews/1/edit
  def edit
    # Calls all user related params and ids from a before action above.

  end

  def create
    # Below -  Creates a WUL City Review for the city using the "city_review_params" method in "private" below, passing
      # attributes for the :title, :score, :description, :city_review_score_id, :user_id, and :city_id, taggings list (:love_list, :improve_list) and assigning the Review to the city.
    @new_city_review = @city.city_reviews.build(city_review_params)
    # Below - Sets the user id to the current user posting the city review
    @new_city_review.user_id = current_user.id 
    # Below - Sets the City Review ID to the current users city's ID.
    @new_city_review.city_id = current_user.city.id
    # Below - Sets the City Review Score Id to the associated city id which should match the City Score ID column.
    @new_city_review.city_review_score_id = current_user.city.id
    # Begin - If statement for determining if the City Review was committed to the DB successfully, then rendering the City Reviews 
      # show page with a success message, or displaying an error and rendering a new form page.
    if @new_city_review.save # If it saves, display Flash message success, if not move to 'else'
      flash[:notice] = "Your What You Love review for #{@city.name} has been successfully posted!"   # Shows a Flash message of success
      redirect_to city_review_path(@city, @new_city_review)  # Redirects to the City Review's show page.
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Could not post your What You Love review for #{@city.name}. See why below!"   # Shows a Flash message of error
      render 'new' # Reload the New template with errors
    end # End - If statement for review creation.
  end

  def update
    # Calls all user related params and ids from a before action above.
    @city_review.user_id = current_user.id 
    # Below - Sets the City Review ID to the current users city's ID.
    @city_review.city_id = current_user.city.id
    # Below - Sets the City Review Score Id to the associated city id which should match the City Score ID column.
    @city_review.city_review_score_id = current_user.city.id

    if @city_review.update(city_review_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Your What You Love Review has been updated successfully!"
      redirect_to city_review_path(@city, @city_review)
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Your What You Love Review could not be updated. See why below!"
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    # Calls all user related params and ids from a before action above.
    if @city_review.user === current_user
      if @city_review.destroy
        flash[:alert] = "Your What You Love review has been deleted."
        redirect_to city_review_index_path(@city)
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Below - Finds the City Review ID from the params
    def set_city_review
      @city_review = CityReview.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Below - Sets up the city for City Review
    def set_city
      @city = City.friendly.find(params[:city_id])
    end

    def city_review_params
      params.require(:city_review).permit(:id, :title, :description, :score, :user_id, :city_id, :city_review_score_id, :love_list, :improve_list)
    end

    # Below - Sets up user related params on edit, update and destroy.
    def set_user_params 
      @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
      @city_review = CityReview.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @city = @city_review.city.friendly_id
      @city_review_edit = @city_review
    end 
    # Takes the user submitted Score value (1..1.5..) out of 5, empties the existing params (:score),
      # multiplies it by 20 to get a percentage value out of 100, and reassigns the params to the newly
        # multiplied value.
    def multiply_score
      user_score = params[:city_review].delete(:score).to_f
      score = user_score * 20
      params[:city_review][:score] = score
    end
end
```

My relevant model code for ActsAsTaggableOn:

```
   acts_as_taggable_on :love, :improve
```

I used, per ActsAsTaggableOn gem suggestion, their migration setup by running the command:

> rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations

And this is how my schema looks for those tables:

```
 create_table "taggings", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tag_id"
    t.string "taggable_type"
    t.integer "taggable_id"
    t.string "tagger_type"
    t.integer "tagger_id"
    t.string "context", limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.index ["context"], name: "index_taggings_on_context"
    t.index ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "tagger_id", "context"], name: "taggings_idy"
    t.index ["taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id"
    t.index ["taggable_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id_and_tagger_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true
  end
```

In attempt to troubleshoot this, I tried a lot of different things, such as rolling back migrations, reinstalling the gem, changing the name of the lists, using the default, using it on a different model, and a few different controller actions. Also, in the code, you'll also see the presence of FriendlyID Gem.

Thank you so much for reading and your assistance.

*To temporarily fix this ActsAsTaggableOn issue with Rails 5.2, use a branch from Fodoj called rails-5.2. In your gemfile add the git link and branch to acts-as-taggable-on gem and then run *bundle install* and restart your server:*

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', :git => 'https://github.com/Fodoj/acts-as-taggable-on', :branch => 'rails-5.2'
```

Comment: Ran into this today, thanks for posting this. Saved me a bit of time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/874) on this and an open [PR](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/pull/887) as well. Please go through these issues

You can use the gem from those branches (or) you can have your own fork with a fix for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Narashimha.